# jQuery AJAX callbacks do not fire in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My jQuery AJAX callbacks, `window.location.href = url;`, do not work in Firefox. It's working fine with Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE. Any solution for this problems?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Wait/Redirect",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { 
        strurl: '123', 
        dipatureDetails: patureDetails 
    },
    dataType:'text',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.ok) {
            var host = "http://" + window.location.hostname;
            var url = host + ":" + location.port + data.newurl;
            window.location.href = url;
        }                       
    }
});
```

Comment: Either your AJAX request is not returning 200 OK as a HTTP response, or the `data.ok` property is false. Check the network tab of the console to check the response type, and use `console.log` to debug the returned data - assuming it's getting that far. I would also strongly suggest you remove `async: false`.

Comment: If i removed async: false, then it not fire in url(url: "/Wait/Redirect")

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a `preventDefault()` somewhere. If you can add your full code we can offer more useful help.

Comment: How can `data` be an object when you are using `dataType:'text'`?

Comment: Yes, make that dataType:'json'

Comment: i have changed data type as json, but problem is same.

Comment: Thanks you Rory McCrossan . It works :)